# Recommendation on Mule JMS queue config

Tags: jms, message-queue, mule

I'm working on updating an existing Mule configuration and the task is to enhance it to route messages to different endpoints depending on some properties of the messages, therefore it would be nice to have some pros and cons on the two options I have at hand:

1. Add properties on the message, using the "message-properties-transformer" transformer which is later used by a "filtering-router" to single out the message and put it on the correct endpoint. This option allows me to use a single queue for all destinations.
2. Create one queue for each destination and thus instead of adding some property for later routing, I just put on on the right queue at once. I.e. this option would mean one queue per destination.

Any feedback would be welcome. Is there any "best practices" with regards to this?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a great deal of success with using your first approach with a filtering-router. It reduces cohesion between your message producers and consumers. It forms a valuable abstraction, so any service can blindly drop messages within the generic "outbox".

We've come to depend on mule for filtering and routing messages so much so that we have a dedicated cluster of hardware to do only this. Using mule I was able to get far greater performance and not have to maintain connections to all queues.

The down side will be having to very carefully maintain your messaging object version globally, and having to keep a set of transformers on hands to accept and convert from different versions if you plan to upgrade only a portion of your infrastructure.

thanks, matt